# How to test a project generated by Maven archetype

Tags: java, maven-archetype

I have created an archetype using Maven which creates a project. 
To test the project, I usually have to generate the project and run the `mvn clean install` to make sure it builds successfully.

I was looking for a way to test that the project which will be generated from archetype builds successfully without having to manually create it.

The option I already considered is that I can write a shell script which can generate the project and test that it works. So, the user will just have to run the script to make sure the archetype project does not fail.

Is there any better way that anyone can suggest?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a test project for each folder placed under src/test/resources/projects.

Each folder must contain :

- a archetype.properties file
- a goal.txt file

Example :

- src/test/resources/projects/
- test1

  - goal.txt
  - archetype.properties

The archetype file contains all properties ("name=value" syntax) that you need to generate the project.
The goal file contains the mvn goal you want to perform (eg : verify)

Then you add the following plugin to the pom.xml of your archetype :

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1 </version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

You can perform your integration test with : `mvn archetype:integration-test`

Reference : https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html